# iOS native library Xamarin binding

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, binding

The problem has already been discussed earlier, but I got it after the update in September. Environment: the latest vs studio for mac, all the frameworks are updated, I also tried to switch to the preview channel, the error is the same. Actually the problem: after the update, the error of creating a native object began to appear.

From my renderer to - at Foundation.NSObject.InitializeObject (System.Boolean alloced) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.2.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:196 at Foundation.NSObject..ctor (Foundation.NSObjectFlag x) [0x0000d] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.2.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:131 at UIKit.UIResponder..ctor (Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.2.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIResponder.g.cs:69 at UIKit.UIView..ctor (Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.8.2.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIView.g.cs:83

Error message: Could not create an native instance of the type 'xxx': the native class hasn't been loaded. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

if set ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure = false; - native constructor returns null;

lib in Binding project is fat, all architectures are supported. i have no its code, only headers. ApiDefinition and Structs generated by sharpie, and works well.

mtouch options: --optimize=-remove-dynamic-registrar

please give some ways to solve, project is on fire.. 
If exist way to rollback all mono frameworks i can try, but its not good way.

Comment: Hi , do you have a try with rebuild native library ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hello, i cant do this, its not my library. But i know exactly that library works in native objc project.

Comment: Facing same issue while binding a framework. any updates or solution ?